# Bootstrap3 --- How to split a page if it is a mobile device?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a registration page in my application. And I want to split into 2 pages if the user is using a mobile phone. Could someone please suggest me some code to achieve this in Bootstrap 3?

Comment: Do you mean "split a page vertically/horizontally"? Or do you mean, "make two separate HTML pages" instead of one when the user is using a mobile device?

Comment: What are you using as your server side language?

Comment: I want to make it as 2 separate HTML pages...

Comment: You could maybe fake 2 pages by using tabs? Something like [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/loginregister-in-tabbed-interface) or [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panel-with-tabs)?

Comment: But what is the bootstrap code to recognize whether it is a mobile device or desktop????

Comment: @GuptaKatakam You cannot tell if it's a mobile device or a desktop, only what size the viewport is. It's all in the documentation - have a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is mobile ready out of the box. Did you read the docs? Everything is more or less explained there - http://getbootstrap.com/ - look at the [grid systems](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) docs and responsive that Olly mentioned